# How to make a for loop that goes through an array and outputs one time if the username is correct

Tags: javascript, html

This is my html code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>ZZ Test</TITLE>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css" />    
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type = "text" id = "input" onblur = "check(this.value)">
    <div id = "picture"></div>


    <script src = "js/main.js"></script>
</BODY>
```

This is my javascript code :

```
var names = ["Arsenij","Vadimster","Charlie"];


function check(answer){
    for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
    if(answer === names[i]){
        alert("This username already exists");
    }
    else {
        alert("Username Ok!");
    }   
};
};
```

The css code just positions the div picture so it is horizonatal the div

How do you make the js code output 1 time if the username doesn't exist?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply check if name `exists` in array or not using `indexOf` method of array

```
function check(answer) {
if (names.indexOf(answer) > -1)
   alert("name exists");
else
   alert("name doesn't exists");

};
```

Currently your code will loop as many times as `length of array`.

Also when you find a `match` you are not `breaking` the `loop` so your loop will run until last element of array.

Comment: I find this answer best among all.. But you are suppose to highlight the issue OP had in his code ;)...+1

Comment: @Rayon i have added details i hope i have explained it well if you want to add something you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) the `for` loop

```
  function check(answer){
    for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
      if(answer === names[i]){
        alert("This username already exists");
        break;
      }
      else {
        alert("Username Ok!");
        break;
      }   
    };
  };
```

Comment: Your loop seems to end on the first iteration regardless of what's stored in `answer`. Shouldn't you check the other values in the rest of the array?

Comment: @PakkuDon Not entirely certain about exact meaning of "1 time" at _"How do you make the js code output 1 time if the username doesn't exist?"_ . If `alert("This username already exists");` is to be called for each iteration, `break` within `if` could be removed. Attempted to convey how to break a `for` loop; OP should be able to remove one of the two `break` statements to achieve requirement; or, further clarify expected result of "make the js code output 1 time"

Answer (score 1):

An alternative running the loop to the end:

```
var names = ["Arsenij","Vadimster","Charlie"];

function check(answer){
    var existent = false;
    for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
         if(answer === names[i]){
             existent = true;
         }
    }
    if(existent){
        alert("This username already exists");
    } else {
        alert("Username Ok!");
    }
}

check("Bob")//alerts "Username OK!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .includes() option to avoid for loop for faster search

```
        function check(answer){
    if(names.includes(answer)){
       alert("This username already exists");
    }
      else{
        alert("Username Ok!"); 
      }
    };
```

codepen URL-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NrRgWe

Comment: Consider [__`Browser compatibility`__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

1) change the `"onblur"` attribute with `"onchange"`

```
    function check(answer){  
    var contain=names.indexof(answer);  
    if(contain==-1){  
        alert("Username Ok!");  
      }  
    else {  
        alert("This username already exists");  
    }     
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = ["Arsenij","Vadimster","Charlie"];


function check(answer){
    for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
    if(answer === names[i]){
        alert("This username already exists");
        break;
    }
    else {
        alert("Username Ok!");
        break;
    }   
};
};
```

Comment: Hi there Seeker, welcome to SO and thank you for your answer. Can you edit your post to explain how this solves the OP's problem?